# How can I create an image tooltip hover over form labels with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, tooltip

How can I put an image tooltip on the label of all radio buttons within a form?  I am using simple_form to generate the form markup, so each label has a for attribute (e.g. `for="reward_id_79"`) that I could use to link the label with its corresponding image `img src='blah.jpg' id='reward_id_79'`.

Each radio input will have an associated image that I'd like to display in a tooltip popup with the user hovers over the label text.  I'd like not to alter the simple_form output, but instead have a series of hidden images elsewhere in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the poshytips jquery plugin.

http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/

It does pretty much what you need and is really easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [jQuery tooltip plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) you could try,  which looks like quite full-featured.